# UILabel text color transparency with layer shadows in place?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` to which I am attempting to apply a semi-transparent gradient as a color onto.  For example, in my `UILabel` subclass I'm trying to set the gradient color this way:

```
self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:someTransparentGradient];
```

While messing around with this, however, I discovered that a `UILabel` doesn't seem to be able to draw with transparency **when layer shadows are in place**.  I attempted to set the text color to clear:

```
self.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but the text ended up being white.  Ideas?

*You can replicate the problem yourself if you set the text color to clear, then apply layer shadows onto the text view.*

Comment: Where did you set the textColor? ie., `self.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: I set it in a custom method from within my `UILabel` subclass.

Comment: Do you have `opaque` set to `YES`?

Comment: @MarkAdams: `opaque` is set to `NO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally accept my own answers, but in this case I must.  This seems to be a bug.  Whenever layer shadows are applied to a `UILabel`, text transparency is no longer supported.  I will file a radar.

Answer (score 3):

If you would have created the `UILabel` through nib and set the textColor in `initWithFrame`, you will not get desired result.

In the `UILabel` sub-class, write `initWithCoder` and set the color.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Edit**

See, this is the screen shot with default (gray) background.

[image]

And this is the screenshot with white background

[image]

Please download the [sample application](http://cl.ly/33420g0N190e2f2C1C0N) and try it.

Comment: I did create the `UILabel` through a nib file, but I didn't override `initWithFrame`, because that's not called if it's instantiated from a nib.  I have a custom initializer that is called after the standard `initWithCoder:`.  But if you actually try your method with `[UIColor clearColor]`, you will see that the text is still white.

Comment: I tried with `clearColor`. If it is clearColor, then the text is not visible. So make sure you set the color inside `initWithCoder`

Comment: I have uploaded the test application. Please download and try it.

Comment: @Aadhira: Yep, figured it out why your project works and not mine.  I'm applying a shadow to the layer.  Try it out and you'll see.