# Custom UIColor created from colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha, alpha Parameter is not being applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicolor

I am currently creating a color like this:

```
+(UIColor *) colorForGlobalMenuItemCellFont {return [UIColor colorWithRed:144.0/255.0 green:146.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];}
```

and I assign it like this:

```
self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorForGlobalMenuItemCellFont];
```

However, the alpha seems to not be working. It always results in being a full opacity, and not the 0.5 that I specified. If I change it to 1.0, it is the same thing as 0.5 or even 0.2.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you sure the line that sets textColor is being hit (try adding a breakpoint), 2. Are you applying layer shadows to the UILabel? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722857/uilabel-text-color-transparency-with-layer-shadows-in-place Can you post some screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a floating point number. Try writing `0.5f`
and yes write the function as `[self colorForGlobalMenuItemCellFont]`;

Comment: double will be implicitly type cast to float so it doesn't matter (at least in the context of this question).